# "And" in negative sentences with "haven’t got"/ "hasn’t got"

Tags: conjunctions

Are these sentences correct?:

> I haven’t got freckles **and** glasses.
>
> She hasn’t got straight, blond hair **and** freckles.
>
> He hasn't got glasses **and** freckles.

Can I use **"and"** with negative sentences with **"haven’t got"**/ **"hasn’t got"?**

Is it correct?
Or should I use **"or"**?

Comment: First off, the punctuation is wrong. You need to use “” or  ‘’ for quote marks in English.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In negative sentences you would usually use "or" rather than "and":

> I don't like A or B.
>
> I don't have A or B.

The exception is if "A and B" is a common expression to represent a single thing ("peanut butter and jelly" sandwiches, "rack-and-pinion" steering, "Abbot and Costello" comedy duo), or where you want to explicitly apply the negative to both together:

> You can't have A or B (You can't have either A or B).
>
> You can't have A and B.  (You can have A, or you can have B, but you can't have both)

So in your examples, it would make more sense to use "or"

> I haven't got freckles or glasses.

Answer (score 3):

In english you can use both *'and'* or *'or'* depending on what you are saying.

***'and':***

1/ will probably appear in longer sentences which are compounded of some number of shorter sentences with a number of "don't"s, "didn't"s, etc...

2/ will appear if you are talking about something as a unit (as a one thing).

***'or'*** will probably appear in sentences which are not compounded of while short sentences.

I'll use some examples to clarify what I mean:

> I don't like apples or oranges but I'm fine with grapes.

Here *'oranges'* is not part of a compounded sentence thus *'or'* is used here naturally.

Now let's take a look how to change it to have *'and'* present:

> I don't like apples and I don't like oranges but grapes are fine.

As you can see now *'and'* connects two *independent* sentences. While in the example before *'oranges'* needed first part of the sentence to make sense (*'I don't like'*).

*Note: Of course you can have longer pieces of text put together with 'or' too as long as they are dependent.*

Lastly, using *'and'* to form a unified *image*:

> I don't like apple and orange mixed juice but I'm fine with either apple or
>   orange one separately.

Here I'm talking about a unit of apple and orange juice together while I can still have a different opinion about each of them.

Natives prefer or because it's shorter, unless you have a special reason to go a different way.

Lastly, I'd like to mention other possibilities which are commonly used:

> I don't like either apples or oranges.
>   I like neither apples nor oranges.

So your sentences would probably be better with just *'or'* unless you are trying to express it as a unit as explained above.

This is what I was taught perhaps somebody can clarify it better.

Answer (score -1):

You use **or** in negative sentences.

Comment: So I can't use "and" in my examples?

Comment: As Vico Lemp's answer suggests, you can, but only in certain ways. **Or** tends to be more common.

Comment: What about my examples? Are they correct, natural?

Comment: In your examples, the first is okay with **and**, but the others should use **or**.

Comment: Even the last example? It's similar to the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You can use and there, but or is preferred throughout all these. When you use and, it gives an implication that a correction may be coming. For example, **He hasn't got glasses and freckles, he's got acne and glasses**, which is why or is preferred since it connotes more a mere description, at least in my dialect.